# if x =0.9% then what is 100%?

Tags: percentages

This is to track hit rate on sales of items and for the life of me I can't visualise how to do it!

I have a value of 312 which represents a hit rate of 0.97% of transactions.

I need to work out what  the 100% number of transactions is.

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand your question but it seems to me that [cross-multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication) could help you solve your problem. In particular you can look at the Rule of Three which comes with an example at the bottom of the previous link.

Comment: I must have phrased this badly, apologies. I know that 312 is 0.97% of transactions in that day. I need to work out what the total number of transactions in that day was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment we can use the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication). Let $n$ be the total number of transactions in the day then we have:
$$
\frac{312}{n} = \frac{0.97}{100}
$$
and using the rule of three we obtain:
$$
n = \frac{312 \times 100}{0.97}\text{.}
$$

---

A different, and maybe simpler, way to get the result stated above is to notice that:
\begin{align}
&&312 ={}& n\times 0.97\% \\
&\Leftrightarrow& 312 ={}& n\times \frac{0.97}{100}
\end{align}

Comment: Aha, I was putting them into the wrong part, thanks for that.